# Can't find proper form of power series derivative

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I've got a power series sum function defined as:

$$f(x) = \sum _{n=1} ^\infty (-1)^n \frac{2n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n-1}, \quad \text{for } x \in ]-R, R[$$

I have already determined the radius of convergence which is infinite, but now I have to show that the second order derivative is the following:

$$f''(x) = \sum _{n=2} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)} \frac{1}{(2n-3)!} x^{2n-3}$$

I understand that $f''(x) = n(n-1)a_n(x-a)^{n-2}$, but I can't seem to get it on the same form as requested, so I feel like I'm missing something. I know the series can be represented with cos and sin, but I think thats the wrong way to go on this one. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Double dollar signs for display style math.

Comment: Ah thanks, was wondering how to center the equations.

Comment: $\left(x^{2n-1}\right)''=(2n-1)(2n-2)x^{2n-3}$ and $\frac{2n(2n-1)(2n-2)}{(2n+1)!}=\frac1{2n+1}\frac1{(2n-3)!}$

Comment: it should be $$\frac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x^2}$$

Comment: Thanks, was not aware that the expression could be simplified like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just observe that $$\frac{2n}{(2n+1)!}=\frac1{(2n+1)(2n-1)!}$$

Hence

$$\frac{2n(2n-1)(2n-2)}{(2n+1)!}=\frac1{(2n+1)(2n-3)!}$$

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
f''(x) &= \sum _{n=1} ^\infty (-1)^n (2n-1)(2n-2)\frac{2n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n-3}\\
&=\sum _{n=1} ^\infty (-1)^n (2n-1)(2n-2)\frac{2n}{(2n+1)2n(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)!} x^{2n-3}\\
&=\sum _{n=1} ^\infty (-1)^n \frac{2n}{(2n+1)2n(2n-3)!} x^{2n-3}\\
&=\sum _{n=2} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(2n-3)!} x^{2n-3}
\end{align}